# How do i extend a class which needs a ClassTag AND to extend Comparable?

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a simple class I always implement when working with a new Language, MergeSort.  So I am looking at my implementations of it with type Int and it looks great.  Then I wanted to genericize it. I started with a simple implementation of T, but i noticed that needed to relfect the ClassTag.  How do i assign the reflected ClassTag + extending?

```
class MergeSort[T: scala.reflect.ClassTag] {
  var array: Array[T] = Array[T]()
  var length: Int = 0
  var tempArray: Array[T] = new Array(length)

  def sort(data: Array[T]): Unit = {
    array = data;
    length = data.length;
    tempArray = new Array[T](length)
    //sort(0, length - 1)
  }
}
```

Now this looks nice!  It works, but when I i do the sort and rest of the functionality, I need to be able to compare 2 items of type T.  The "Java" way was to just make sure the Object has the `compareTo` method.   So i was thinking: `[T extends Comparable]`

but in scala, I am doing assignment for T with ClassTag, and

`class MergeSort[T: scala.reflect.ClassTag extends Comparable] {}` for example.  It will error saying:

> ']' expected, but 'extends' found.

I was thinking this would sorta be the way to do things, but i am not sure whats going on here.

The endstate is to implement the merge portion of the class:

```
def merge(lower: Int, center: Int, upper: Int){
  // ...
  
  // loop
  //  if (tempArr(i) <= tempArr(j)) {}  // OLD WAY, since First attempt was with Int.
  //  if (tempArr(i).compareTo(tempArr(j)) < 0) {}   // Modified way with Comparable
}
```

Is this the scala way of implementing?  I was noticing that people were mentioning Ordering, but i thought Comparable made sense.

Comment: The syntax you want is `[T <: Comparable : ClassTag]` or you may use `Ordered` instead of `Comparable` which is the proper **Scala** trait. - Or, even better, use the `Ordering` typeclass instead of `Ordered` which nobody uses thus the syntax would be `[T : Ordering : ClassTag]` or you could not use the sugar syntax but rather just normal implicit parameters like `class MergeSort[T](implicit ev1: Ordering[T], ev2: ClassTag[T])` - Or, you may rather try to properly learn the language instead of just its syntax and write an immutable merge sort using `List` instead of `Arrays` + `vars`

Comment: Yeah, was curious about that.  One of the things I was thinking is that while I am in fact creating it, it compiles, and runs ( well the Int case ) and words, i was thinking that there was an Alternative Method which might be more "Scala" i guess.  

My Logic was that I wanted to do an In Memory Replace of the passed in Array, which is contradictory to a immutable Variation with List.

Comment: Note, after understanding more of scala, I am planning to rewrite it better, but since I wanted to do an In Memory sort and not RETURN a new List, is why i will likely retain the Array as my primary data type for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The Scala way of implementing merge sort is using `List` and `val`s and the `Ordering` trait. The advantage of `Ordering` (the Java Comparator) is that Scala gives you implicit orderings for all standard library types by default.

```
  def msort[T: Ordering](xs: List[T]): List[T] = {
    @tailrec
    def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T], acc: List[T] = Nil): List[T] =
      (xs, ys) match {
        case (Nil, _) => acc.reverse ++ ys
        case (_, Nil) => acc.reverse ++ xs
        case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
          if (implicitly[Ordering[T]].lt(x, y))
            merge(xs1, ys, x :: acc)
          else
            merge(xs, ys1, y :: acc)
      }

    xs match {
      case Nil | _ :: Nil => xs
      case _ =>
        val (xs1, xs2) = xs splitAt (xs.length / 2)
        merge(msort(xs1), msort(xs2))
    }
  }

  msort(List(4, 23, 1, 2, 5, 76, 3, 142, 4321, 213, 42323)) 
  // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 23, 76, 142, 213, 4321, 42323)
  msort(List("John", "Chris", "Helen", "Danny", "Michelle")) 
  // List(Chris, Danny, Helen, John, Michelle)
```

Another advantage over `Ordered` is that Scala provides implicit conversions from `Ordered[A] => Ordering[A]`, which means your custom types that mix in `Ordered` will work with `msort` without the need to define implicit orderings.

Finally, the last advantage over `Ordered` is when using numeric types: `Int`, `Double`, etc. do not mix in `Ordered`, so you will not be able to sort elements of these types with `Ordered`, this is why most use `Ordering` instead.

I'm well aware this variant is not in-memory, but it does not require `ClassTag` at all to implement.

Comment: I do not like this answer.  The reason being is that you are using recursion.  I have it solved in an Iterative Manor, which consumes far less stack space.  Similarly, the goal is to do an in memory swap and not create a new List and return it.  At Worst case My Space allowance is 2N and is runs optimally.  At Scale Recursion can run out of memory quicker than an iterative solution from my tests.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Indeed it's not tail-recursive and will overflow. The example is from Odersky's book, so I didn't had a good look at it. But it's easy to change it into a tail-recursive version. I just edited my answer. Now it's equivalent to an iterative solution. This would require at most 2*N space as well and will run optimally. Yes, in-memory swap is always faster, that's why qsort is faster in practice than msort, but msort has the advantage of being a stable sort and guaranteeing N*logN complexity, beating qsort in worst-case scenarios. That's why the standard Sorting reference uses both.